# How does WiFi Lobby of Pocket Tanks work?

Tags: android, wifi, multiplayer

There's a game called Pocket Tanks. What it offers is that 2 players can connect to same WiFi Network (like in home) and play the game together. Its different from internet multiplayer. It just needs common WiFi. I want to know how to implement such a system in my android game. I've tried to search it on Google but no helpful results. Any idea where do I even begin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The app probably has a socket open listening on a certain port.
Then when it searches for other phones, it just tries to connect to other IP addresses on that port.

Comment: Is that certain port hardcoded into app? Because if it's not, then how'd the other client know where to connect. Am I right?